# Is there some plugin for Sublime Text 2 to encode images to base64

Tags: base64, encode, sublimetext2

There is cool [plugin](http://www.midwinter-dg.com/downloads_coda-plugin_base64-encode-images.html) for Coda to encode images to base64 string by selecting the image path in code and then pressing hotkey.

Is there such one for Sublime Text 2? I found only one base64 encoder in Package Control set, but It encode only strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's included in [Emmet](http://emmet.io/download/) (formerly Zen Coding) Place your caret on an image, goto command palette and type "Encode/Decode Image" (or just "base" in Zen Coding), hit enter.

Comment: For future reference, Zen Coding is now Emmet and the command is currently "[Encode/Decode Image to data:URL](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/base64/ "Why they couldn't use the word 'base' in that, I don't know")"